# Can't implement Remember Me functionality to FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I'm using FormsAuthentication for logging. What I want is when user checks "Remember Me" option, make cookie never expire. My problem is whenever I try to change cookie expiration time either `Request.IsAuthenticated` becomes *false* with`Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value` equals *null* or `Request.IsAuthenticated` returns always *true*. My codes are below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(PortalUserModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            uzm_portaluser user = _defDal.GetPortalUser(model.Username, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Id.ToString(), true);
                if (model.isRemember)
                {
                    //Tried to increase expire time here using various ways but none of them worked

                }

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user;
                return RedirectToAction(defaultAction, defaultController);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Wrong username or password";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Wrong username or password";
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
    }
```

I tried these but as I said none of them worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851344

(This one makes `Request.IsAuthenticated`true but `Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]` is empty. Most of the solutions are like this)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10773495/2564339

(This one did not work at all)

Comment: Have you considered using Owin middleware ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179352/owin-cookies-vs-formsauthentication/26190205#26190205. This blog has been helpfull for me https://tomasherceg.com/blog/post/modernizing-asp-net-web-forms-applications-part-2

Comment: Well, I had to finish it quickly. So I couldn't but I will. Thanks. Question is still valid, though.